# Flutter web : getx middleware and route arguments (GetX example_nav2)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-getx

1. Getx example_nav2
   https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/tree/master/example_nav2
2. my app_pages.dart

```dart
            GetPage(
            preventDuplicates: true,
            name: _Paths.sRoot,
            page: () => const SellerDashBoardRootView(),
            binding: SellerDashBoardRootViewBinding(),
            middlewares: [
              //only enter this route when user is a seller
              EnsureAuthSeller()
            ],
            children: [

              GetPage(
                name: _Paths.sellerDashboard,
                page: () => const SellerDashboardScreen(),
                binding: SellerDashboardBinding(),
                transition: Transition.fadeIn),

              GetPage(
                preventDuplicates: true,
                name: _Paths.sProductsRoot,
                page: () => const SellerProductsRootView(),
                binding: SellerProductsRootViewBinding(),
                transition: Transition.fadeIn,
              ),

              GetPage(
                name: _Paths.sellerProducts,
                page: () => const SellerProductsScreen(),
                binding: SellerProductsBinding(),
                transition: Transition.fadeIn,
                children: [

                  GetPage(
                  name: _Paths.sellerAddProduct,
                  page: () => const SellerAddProductScreen(),
                  binding: SellerAddProductBinding(),
                  transition: Transition.fadeIn),

                  GetPage(
                  name: _Paths.sellerStock,
                  page: () => const SellerStockScreen(),
                  binding: SellerStockBinding(),
                  transition: Transition.fadeIn),

                 ],
               ),
             ]
           )
```

3. EnsureAuthSeller (GetMiddleware)

```
class EnsureAuthSeller extends GetMiddleware {
  @override
  Future<GetNavConfig?> redirectDelegate(GetNavConfig route) async {
    if (!AuthService().isLogin) {
      return null;
    } else {
      var role = await LocalStorageServices().getUserRole(keyRole);
      if (role != "seller") {
        return null;
      }
      if (role == "seller") {
        return GetNavConfig.fromRoute(route.location!);
      }
    }
    return await super.redirectDelegate(route);
  }
}
```

4. Passing arguments from Routes.sellerProducts to Routes.sellerAddProduct

Routes.sellerProducts :

```
Map<String, String> productDetails = {"productInfos":"test"};

Get.rootDelegate.toNamed(Routes.sellerAddProduct, arguments: productDetails);
```

Routes.sellerAddProduct :

```
final productDetails = Get.rootDelegate.arguments();
print("result = $productDetails");
```

5. Result

Without EnsureAuthSeller (GetMiddleware) => result = **{"productInfos":"test"}**

With EnsureAuthSeller (GetMiddleware) => result = **null**

Why ? and what is the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `GetNavConfig` using only the location. You should just return the existing `GetNavConfig` from the parameter:

```
if (role == "seller") {
    return route;
  }
```